# Ember Retrieve and link record to a new one

Tags: ember.js

Creating a simple library app, with authors and books. There is a relationship between books and authors (belongsTo / hasMany)

I'm trying to create a new book using `this.route('new', { path: '/new/:author_id' });`

My Route is:

```
App.BooksNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.createRecord('book');
    }
});
```

I know I can retrieve the author_id using `params.author_id` but..

**How can I bind `model.author` to the author record identified by `author_id`**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about routes like these?

```
  this.resource('author', function () {
    this.route('show', {path: '/:author_id'}, function () {
      this.resource('book', function() {
        this.route('new');
      });
    });
  });
```

In this case the author would be available as the model of the `author/show` route ...:

```
this.store.createRecord('book', {author: this.modelFor('author/show')});
```

If you don't have the author already available, you have to get it from the store ...:

```
this.store.find('author', id).then(
  function(author){
    return this.store.createRecord('book', {author: author});
  }
)
```

(Caveat: code untested, but it should show the ideas)